# Is req.user guaranteed to be a valid, authenticated user? [passport.js]

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js, express-session

I want to check if a specific user has permissions which other users dont have.

Assuming I have a list of IDs of the users that have this specific permission, is it save to just compare the req.user.id to the IDs in the list and if there is a match, grant them permission? Can someone send a request and just fill in an ID of someone else?

I am using discord oauth2 with passport, passport-discord and express-session for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation of passportjs. If this is secure (i.e. using signed JWT Tokens and your secret is not leaked) there is no way that someone can spoof another ID and you can trust `req.user.id`!

Comment: I am not using JWT, I am using express-session with a cookie with the session id, which is stored also in a session store DB. I am storing the users (with id) in my database and getting the user by its req.user.id from there when deserializing. Is this safe?

Comment: Yes, if it is properly implemented it is safe!